# I want to browse files and upload to sever in ionic app

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I simply want to browse files on phone and upload it to server. file could be of any type. please guide how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
allScopes.store('uploadCtrl', $scope);
$scope.filetype = { type:""};
$scope.fileUrl="";
$scope.browsefile = function(){                 
    fileChooser.open(
          `enter code here`function (fileUrl) 
            {               
                window.FilePath.resolveNativePath(fileUrl, function(filePath){
                    $scope.filename = filePath.split('/').pop();
                }, function(err){
                    alert(err);
                });
                $scope.fileUrl = fileUrl;
            },
            function (error) {
                alert(error);
            }
        );

    };  

    $scope.uploadFile = function(){     
        alert($scope.filename);
        var filename = $scope.filename;                     
        var accountid = settings.get().userid;      
        var category = $scope.filetype.type;
        var localuri = $scope.fileUrl;

        if($scope.filetype.type!="")
        {                               
            if(localuri!=null)
            {                                                
                var options = {
                    httpMethod: 'POST',                 
                    chunkedMode: false                  
                };
                $cordovaFileTransfer.upload(configParamUrl+"/bulker/uploadmobilefile?filename="+filename+"&accountId="+accountid+"&category="+category, localuri, options).then(function(result) {                      
                    alert(JSON.stringify(result));
                }, function(err) {                      
                    alert(JSON.stringify(err));
                }, function (progress) {
                    alert(progress.loaded);
                    $scope.uploadProgress = Math.ceil((progress.loaded / progress.total) * 100);
                });            
            }
            else
            {               
                $cordovaToast.show('Choose file to Upload', 'long', 'bottom').then(function(success) {}, function (error) {});
            }               
        }       
        else{
            $cordovaToast.show('Choose file type', 'long', 'bottom').then(function(success) {}, function (error) {});           
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use two Cordova plugins:

1. [File Opener 2 plugin](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/fileOpener2/) to allow the user to browse files.
2. [File Transfer plugin](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/fileTransfer/) to upload the file.

A tutorial on how to upload a file using File Transfer Cordova plugin:https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2015/01/upload-files-remote-server-using-ionic-framework/

Comment: file opener not let u to browse file. I tested, it let u open pdf file in pdf viewer app(like WPS Office).

Comment: http://www.digitalnoiz.com/mobile-development/mobile-file-explorer-with-phonegapcordova-and-jquery-mobile-part-1/

Comment: Somebody help to sort this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that you can use basic HTML File Input on Mobile (Haven't tested this out)

```
<input type='file' />
```

It will give you the open to choose where you want to get the file from (Camera, Explorer).

And I haven't tried this plugin out on Ionic but it works well on web apps so hope it should work on Ionic.

https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-file-upload

Comment: simple input file let you to  browse file but not actualy pick file. I did it successfuly on browser. In browser i browse file n upload it sucessfuly to server no issue there. but when i build apk & test in phone it not working.

Comment: If somebody know help with code or suggest hw i achieve it.